get user's posts flutter php
basically i made a page where the user can posts , after he posts it shows in  the home page with others posts , i want to make a page that shows  the posts that the user posted only
i made this interface with flutter
when i click at the posts page , i get a message shows Failed to load posts even tho the user has posted before
class UserPostsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<UserPostsPage> createState() => _UserPostsPageState();
}

class _UserPostsPageState extends State<UserPostsPage> {
  List userPosts = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchUserPosts();
  }

  Future<void> fetchUserPosts() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? userId = prefs.getString('userid');
    if (userId != null) {
      var url = Uri.parse("$GETMYPOSTS?userId=$userId");
      var response = await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
        setState(() {
          userPosts = jsonData;
        });
      } else {
        print('Failed to load posts');
      }
    }
  }
.....
  

and this is the php code :
<?php 

include("../connect.php");

$userid = isset($_GET['userid']) ? $_GET['userid'] : null;

if (!$userid) {
   
    http_response_code(400); 
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'User ID is required']);
    exit;
}
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM post_table WHERE author = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $userid); 

$list = array();

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $list[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($list);
} else {
  
    http_response_code(500); 
    echo json_encode(['error' => $stmt->error]);
}

$stmt->close();
?>

PS : there are two tables that im using
post_table : author
and user: userid
tbh i dont know where is the problem exactly

Have you tried calling http_response_code(200); if the stmt executes successfully?

I don't know PHP, try testing your API with Postman or Swagger. Also I would recommend using some sort of future builder or listview builder in your case to fetch data from an API.
Read this: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data
and use a ListView builder instead

i dont know where is the problem exactly...try doing some debugging, then! We can't run your code, we can only stare at it. If there isn't a clear and obvious syntax or logic error, then we'll rely on your accurately reporting the behaviour of the code in order to know specifically what it's doing, and where things aren't behaving as you expected it to at that moment. As mentioned above, first use a tool like PostMan to check that the PHP part is working as expected. Once you're happy that passes all your tests, then move on to integrating it with the flutter code.

@PeterKoltai 200 is the default status if you don't set one, so that's very unlikely to achieve anything. (And if PHP was planning not to send a 200 response for some reason, then overriding that is just going to hide any problems rather than help to reveal them)

If you aren't getting a 200 response from PHP, it suggests it's failing somehow. So you need to a) turn on PHP error logging (if you haven't already) and check your logs when you've run the code, and b) test and debug the PHP separately as we mentioned. Once you have a specific error/problem, if you can't fix it yourself then post the details here (you can [edit] your question) to see if we can help.

One thing I notice is that you have "$GETMYPOSTS?userId=$userId" in the flutter, but isset($_GET['userid']) in the PHP. The key will be case-sensitive, so then userid won't be found, and you'd get the 400 response. Note that your flutter code ignores the output from PHP when there's an error, so you haven't seen the helpful message that PHP outputs to explain the problem. Try using $GETMYPOSTS?userid=$userId in the flutter, and see if that helps.
